# How generate HTML sitemap via mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to build html sitemap with 500 link for each sitemap page. my site has more than 10,000 post.

my **sitemap.php** file

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 500" );
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<a href='http://".$data['url']. "'>".$data['title']. "</a>";
echo "<br>";
}
```

how to get another 500 post via URL parameter?

**/sitemap.php?=2** or

**/sitemap.php?=501&1000**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/sitemap.php?=2 or
/sitemap.php?=501&1000
```

This won't work. You will have to use parameter names, e.g. like this:

```
/sitemap.php?page=2
```

Then get the parameter values using $_REQUEST:

```
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
```

and perform the query accordingly:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id BETWEEN " . (($page - 1) * 500) . " AND " . ($page * 500));
```

P.S. I know, I know... SQL injection, parameter validation, etc. That was not the point.

Comment: SQL injection? This method is not safe?

Comment: This particular one is probably fine since if `$page` isn't a number, the PHP will blow up.  The point that @proskor was making is that someone could pass a URL like `/sitemap.php?page=2;SELECT * FROM *`, and that would eventually get passed into $sql.  In other words, manually building SQL commands is a bad habit, and you should get in the habit of using parameterized queries (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: but i'm getting **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 4**

Comment: Line 4 **$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id BETWEEN " . (($page - 1) * 500) . " AND " . ($page * 500));**

Comment: Hmm, looks fine. Maybe missing semicolon on line 3?

Comment: @nkteam: Any time you build a SQL statement with data that comes from an untrusted source, then you're leaving yourself open to SQL injection.  Learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with PDO instead of the deprecated `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Yes i miss semicolon on line. Thank you @proskor.